# What is Receiving Bounce Notification in google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, notifications

Hi i'm new to Google App Engine.

what is *Receiving Bounce Notification* used for? How does it bounce a notification when there is an email ?

I also read the documentation at [Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/bounce) but I do not understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [bounce notification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounce_message) is when you send an email and the server returns an error. It could be the email address is invalid, the mail box is full .... So if you are planning on sending emails from your app you should setup a bounce notification catcher in case there was an error.

Comment: But i tried it out with my application where i'm sending a mail to my string@appid.appspotmail.com , it is not trigerring the bounce notification ?

Comment: It would be better, if you would share me or direct me on examples for it ?

Comment: Try sending to an email that does not exist. try nowaythisexists@invalidemailtestemailsend.blarg

Comment: Oh thank you ! that's nice. Fine and then what if i'm receiving email in my app will i be able to use the Bounce Notification  on receiving email ?

Comment: Bounce is only for errors. If you want to receive emails you need to do this: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/receivingmail Be aware that you need to store the emails your self (possibly in the datastore)

Comment: Fine, then if there is any error occured while receiving email can i apply bounce Notification on such scenario's?

Comment: As in you send a bounce notification back to the sender?